# Android: Language support, spinner options

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner in my app where the user chooses whether he wants to search by "Contains" "Starts with" "Ends with" or "Equals", The option user selects is stored into a json with other information and sent to server to retrieve results.  Now I'm using:

```
String searchtypeval=searchtype.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

and adding  `searchtypeval` into my json.
The String-array in the spinner is

```
    <string-array name="search_options">
        <item>Starts With</item>
        <item>Equals</item>
        <item>Ends With</item>
        <item>Contains</item>
    </string-array>
```

But now I'm adding language support so in `values-fr/strings.xml` the string array for that spinner is

```
<string-array name="search_options">
    <item>Commence par </item>
    <item>Égal </item>
    <item>Se termine par </item>
    <item>Contient </item>
</string-array>
```

Now if the user selects equals in french , *Egal* is stored into the JSON which of course the server doesn't accept. Is there any way I can make a connection between the french and the english `strings.xml`? All I can think of now is to use `searchtype.getSelectedItemPosition()`
and hard code the value into `String searchtypeval` since I know which option is which position, but this seems very cumbersome, is there any method to solve this issue that is more elegant?

Comment: compare by position is the best bet, another option is fetch the search_options list from server, depending on the language user has selected.

Comment: possibly send an integer to the server instead of a string

Comment: @todd I can't make any changes on server side, have to send the english string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send to the server index of a selected element, but this isn't a good way, cause of index is not informated. The better way is sending readable string key to the server. See the following code:

1) create file **nontranslatable_string.xml** in **res/values**

```
<resources>

 <string-array name="search_options_keys">
        <item>Starts With</item>
        <item>Equals</item>
        <item>Ends With</item>
        <item>Contains</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

2) create your Item class like **SpinnerItem**

```
public class SpinnerItem {

 public final String key;
 public final String value;

 private SpinnerItem(String key, String value) {
  this.key = key;
  this.value = value;
 }

 public static SpinnerItem create(String key, String value) {
  return new SpinnerItem(key, value);
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return value;
 }

}
```

3) fill your adapter with values

```
   String[] keys = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.id.search_options_keys);
   String[] values = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.id.search_options);

   List<SpinnerItem> items = new ArrayList<SpinnerItem>();

   for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    items.add(SpinnerItem.create(keys[i], values[i]));
   }

   spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<SpinnerItem>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, android.R.id.text1, items));
```

4) select your value

```
String valueForSendingToServer = ((SpinnerItem) spinner.getSelectedItem()).key;
```

**UPDATE**

Or you can use another way and get neccessary value for any location you use:

```
      Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();

      // Save originla location
      Locale originalLocal = config.locale;

      // Set new one for single using 
      config.locale = new Locale("en");
      context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);

      // Get search_options array for english values
      String[] searchOptionsEn = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.search_options);

      // Set previous location back
      config.locale = originalLocal;
      getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);

      String valueForSendingToServer = searchOptionsEn[spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()];
```

Comment: Thanks, the update bit is the thing I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can reference string resources in the string-array for localization.

```
<string-array name="search_options">
    <item>@string/starts_with</item>
    <item>@string/equals</item>
    <item>@string/ends_with</item>
</string-array>
```

and then in **res/values/strings.xml**:

```
<string name="starts_with">Starts with </string>
```

and in **res/values-fr/string.xml**:

```
<string name="starts_with">Commence par </string>
```